# What Design Pattern can be used here?

Tags: design-patterns

I am new to Design pattern.
Can anybody help me to identify which design pattern can be used here ?
please provide reason also.

Assume that we would like to model a personal computer (PC). A PC consists of a cabinet, which includes a chassis. A chassis on its turn is composed of a bus, a floppy disk drive, a memory unit, a CPU, and a power supply. A bus incorporates a network card. We would like to treat all the equipment components in a uniform way. The basic operations needed are netPrice and powerConsumption, which return the net price and the power consumption of each component respectively. In addition, each component may have its own specific semantics.

Comment: Sounds like homework. Have you made any own thought? Can you share them here?

Comment: Yes.I think it is creational as we want to create a new Object for pc but i have doubt that it can be structural also as it has group of Objects in it.

Comment: sounds like using an interface is the way to go.. IPCComponent exposes methods GetNetPrice() and GetPowerConsumption(), the code behind these methods can be completely unique between the classes (components).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two main design patterns I'd suggest are the [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) and [Composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) pattern.

Implement two interfaces: `NetPrice` and `PowerConsumption`.

- in `NetPrice`, add the method `getNetPrice`
- in `PowerConsumption`, add the method `getPowerConsumption`

If all of your components require these two methods, consider adding an abstract `ComponentType` implementing these two interfaces. Extend all your other component from this `ComponentType`. This would then allow you to implement each subclass with their own specifics, exposed through the same interface.

For assembling a `PC`, I'd suggest to look into the **Builder pattern**, e.g. build a class with dedicated methods to assemble a computer, e.g. something that would allow you to write code like

```
PCBuilder builder = new PCBuilder();
PC pc = builder
    .cabinet(new Cabinet())
    .chassis(new Chassis))
    .cpu(new Intel())
    .andSoOn()
    .assemble();
```

It' up to the builder to wire the things together in an appropriate way.

I assume you want to get the total net price and power consumption for the PC, so have it implement the same two interfaces we defined in the beginning. This would be a **Composite pattern** then, e.g. the PC would do

```
public double getNetPrice() {
    double sum = 0;
    foreach (this.components as component) {
        sum += component.getNetPrice();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Do the same for components having other components, e.g. if your `Bus` has a `NetworkCard`, `getNetPrice` on the Bus would get the net price of the network card and add it to whatever the Bus might cost. Same for `getPowerConsumption` obviously.

Components not having other components (the leaves in your composite tree) will just return their respective values, e.g. your `NetworkCard` would just

```
public double getNetPrice() {
    return 42.0;
}
```

If you want to print the net prices and power consumption individually, have a look at the [**Visitor pattern**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) instead.

<sup>*Note: you did not mention which language you need this in, so the code examples are pseudo code. I am assuming you will use some sort of object-oriented language supporting things like interfaces and abstraction and stuff.*</sup>

Comment: Hi @Gordon, could you explain why don't you just used a Command Pattern?

Comment: @J.Guilherme can you explain why you think it would be appropriate?

Comment: Because this pattern will hide all specification of each equipment exposing only netPrice and powerConsumption that will be implemented using a interface like:

Comment: Sorry I pressed enter accidentally, btw:

Because command pattern will hide all specification of each equipment exposing only netPrice and powerConsumption that will be exposed using the pattern. Then, when the chassis wants a netPrice they will only use the execute method, using following:

 public interface Command {
  public void execute();
 }

 public class NetPriceCommand : Command {
  private Equipment equipment;

  public NetPriceCommand(Equipment equipment) {
   this.equipment = equipment;
  }

  public void execute() {
   this.equipment.netPrice();
  }
 }

Comment: @J.Guilherme hmm, possible. I find that less intuitive though. Consider adding it as an answer. I don't claim my solution to be the *only* solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Command Pattern in order to hide specifications for each equipment, exposing only methods you want chassis to use.

For this, you create an interface like:

```
public interface Command {
    public void execute();
}
```

Then, you create a class for each method you want chassis to use for each equipment, for example, netPrice():

```
public class NetPriceCommand : Command {
    private Equipment equipment;

    public NetPriceCommand(Equipment equipment) {
        this.equipment = equipment;
    }

    public void execute() {
        this.equipment.netPrice();
    }
}
```

Now, when you want to use newPrice method for a HD, for example, you will instantiate a NetPriceCommand with HD in constructor and then using execute method exposed.

Hope it helps.